# ListView Rendering image issue.

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rendering bytes from sql server to an image control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878033/rendering-bytes-from-sql-server-to-an-image-control)

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvGallery" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
   <LayoutTemplate>
   <table runat="server" id="tableGallery">
   <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">

   </tr>

   </table>

   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>       
   <tr><td>
   <div class="box_img2">
            <div class="g_size">
                <a runat="server" id="linkImage"><img id="Image1" runat="server" src="MyImage.jpg" /></a>
            </div>         
   </div>
   </td></tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Data Source=CHANDAN-PC;Initial Catalog=Metamorphism;User ID=sa;password=chandan;" 
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Image] FROM [GalleryImages]"></asp:SqlDataSource>


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //write your handler implementation here.
            string username = Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["username"]);
            if (username != null)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                byte[] arrContent;
                DataRow dr;
                string strSql;
                strSql = "Select Image from GalleryImages where username = '" + username + "'";
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, connection.ConnectionString);
                da.Fill(ds);
                dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                arrContent = (byte[])dr["ImageFile"];
                context.Response.ContentType = "jpeg";
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(arrContent, 0, arrContent.Length);
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

I have added httphandlers tag in web.config.

Comment: Don't post the same question more then twice

Comment: Fixed contenttype initialization string to: context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this

```
     <div class="box_img2">
                <div class="g_size">
                    <a runat="server" id="linkImage">
<img id="Image1" runat="server" src='<%# Eval( HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"] ,"YourGenericHandler.ashx?username={0}") %>' /></a>
                </div>         
       </div>
```

Comment: How do I pass the username as a parameter along with the source property of img control?

Comment: I updated the code but you can't pass the image object for the handler, you have to pass an id or so and the handler have to fetch the data from the database and return the image.

Comment: Its giving me a parser error while running....I think syntax isnt proper

Comment: I get the following error.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Its not picking up the querystring parameter

Comment: I will make it simple....how do I pass session parameter with my handler. For example: 

src='HttpImageHandler.aspx?username=<%# Session["username"] %>'

Comment: src='<%# Eval( HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] ,"HttpImageHandler.ashx?username={0}") %>'

Comment: BTW, you recieved the argument null exception because the query string don't have a username parameter.